# Swagger: define common parameter for all requests under specific @Api path

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger, springfox

I'm trying to refactor some code and define a commonly used HeaderParameter (lets call it 'myCommonParam' for now) globally for a specific @Api path (once per controller). Otherwise I would have to define the HeaderParameter for each operation/http request in my controller.

After doing some reseach I've found a way to specify `globalOperationParameters` via an springfox configuration (example 1).

example 1:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                ...
                .globalOperationParameters(Collections.singletonList(
                new ParameterBuilder()
                        .name("myCommonParam")
                        .description("my common param.")
                        .modelRef(new ModelRef("string"))
                        .parameterType("header")
                        .required(false)
                        .build())
        );
    }
}
```

The actual issue with this approach is that I have multiple controllers (api paths) and only want the HeaderParameter to apply for some of them. The best solution would be if I could define the commonly used params once per class, like the expectation shows.

actual:

```
@Api(value = "firstController")
public class MyFirstController {

    public void apiOperation_1(@RequestHeader(name = "myCommonParam", required = false) @ApiParam(value = "my common param.", required = false) String myCommonParam){
        // not neccessary
    }

    public void apiOperation_2(@RequestHeader(name = "myCommonParam", required = false) @ApiParam(value = "my common param.", required = false) String myCommonParam){
        // not neccessary
    }
}
```

expected:

```
@Api(value = "firstController")
>>> somehow define the 'myCommonParam' parameter here? <<<
public class MyFirstController {


    public void apiOperation_1(){
        // not neccessary
    }

    public void apiOperation_2(){
        // not neccessary
    }
}
```